# How to convert Object Array to specific attribute value array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert from this array

```
[{"tagid":"422"},{"tagid":"467"},{"tagid":"146"},{"tagid":"097"}]
```

to

```
["422","467","146","097"]
```

Is there a way to convert this without using loop in php, or the best possible method in php?

Comment: Can you define "best", in your view? Fastest? Least lines? Use of functions? Object-oriented? Anything else? It's too vague and subjective a term to be used as a requirement. Also, what's wrong with loops, exactly? A solution with a `foreach` loop will be simple and quick to create for this purpose. And what have you tried and where are you stuck? Normally we expect to _help_ people with their code here, not just design and write it all for them from nothing. Please show your attempt and explain your issue. See the [tour] and [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: my data set is huge. using loop will be not a good solution, but you can suggest loop solution, but it's not worth it. I think issue has been explained very well. Create such json object array/key value array and then convert simple value array as described in my question in PHP. without loop , because i can also use loop. want to know is there any built-in function/ fastest solution.

Comment: define "huge". How many items are we talking about, actually? Have you tried with loops? Was there an actual issue? Don't fall down the rabbit-hole of speculative premature optimisation. Any function you can use is likely to use some sort of loop internally, anyway - you cannot get away from fact that at some point, the code will have to actually look at each item of data and process it. You _might_ get some better performance if that happens to be a built-in PHP function which is actually implemented in C, or the PHP dev can write better loops than you can somehow, but it all depends.

Comment: BTW you should really mention your scenario and constraints, and the reasons for them, in your question, not latterly in the comments when someone asks you to clarify why you're worrying about something which appears to be trivial. If you oversimplify the question, people will wonder why you're asking it!

Comment: It was worth clarifying the scenario, and also encouraging _you_ to think about the problem and define it properly. Lukas took a punt and got lucky. Or maybe you never had a problem to begin with, just an unfounded concern about loops and large datasets (but without ever actually defining what you classed as being large). You did not clarify why you thought there would a problem with loops, it seems you just _assumed_ there would be, which is not a good foundation for writing code.

Comment: P.P.S. Just to emphasis the point, please take a look at the source code of the array_column function (as used by lukas below): https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php . Notice big `foreach` **loop** right there, underpinning the logic of the entire function. So yeah, if you use `array_column` maybe _your_ code doesn't have loops in it, but in the end PHP is still using a loop to process the data. So it doesn't address your supposed concern or remove the use of loops.

Comment: In fact if that solution is acceptable for you (which, since you've accepted the answer containing it, I assume it is), then arguably it proves that you didn't need to be worried about the use of loops at all to begin with. You've just shifted the use of the loop into some subsidiary code, instead of your own. And it's a much more complicated loop than you'd have written to do this yourself - here's a demo of a much simpler loop-based solution: https://3v4l.org/M9PAP . Like I said, beware the danger of assuming performance problems exist before you've actually seen any.

Comment: And also the C version of array_column: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L4277 (as used in the compiled, built-in PHP functions). Again, big loop. As I said above, it being C _might_ give a performance boost in certain circumstances, but you can easily test the two solutions you've now got, to see if that's actually true in practice.

Comment: mentioned above following statement (want to know is there any built-in function/ fastest solution.) but you were stuck in question detailing. Anyways, thanks for letting me know built-in php array_column also uses loop. appreciate that. i wrote in my question best possible method. and reply to your comment as well. but thanks for enhancing my knowledge. my purpose was to perform very less processing on server side. i do not want to increase execution time .

Comment: Ok it's good, your comment clarifies your reason and logic. I did get stuck into the detail, simply because there wasn't all that much of of it in your initial question :-). So yes, you have found a built-in solution, but since you also said you wanted to avoid loops I thought it was good to a) find out why that was, since by itself it's just an arbitrary requirement with no inherent value, and b) then point out that such built-in functions tend to use loops within them anyway. So i think we've got there in the end, and thankyou for removing the rude comment :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = '[{"tagid":"422"},{"tagid":"467"},{"tagid":"146"},{"tagid":"097"}]';

$arr = array_column(json_decode($json, true), 'tagid');
```